# Java: Why Doesn’t My Equals Method Work?

Tags: java, collections

I implemented the equal’s method in my Person object with the @annotation, however, when I create an object in my main class and check it against my List of Person objects, it doesn’t return the correct index. It says they are both at 1, but it should be 1 and 3.

**Objective:**

Check to see if “Andy Bernard” exists in my list and if so, display the index of the objects.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName,String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);  
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (firstName == null) {
            if (other.firstName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
            return false;
        if (lastName == null) {
            if (other.lastName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    private static List<Person> deletePeople = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         addPerson("Micheal","Scott");
         addPerson("Andy","Bernard");
         addPerson("Micheal","Scott");
         addPerson("Andy","Bernard");
         display();

    }

    public static void addPerson(String firstname, String lastname) {
        Person createPerson = new Person(firstname,lastname);
        deletePeople.add(createPerson);
    }

    public static void display() {
        Person checkPerson = new Person("Andy","Bernard");

        for (Person display : deletePeople) {
            if(display.equals(checkPerson)) {
                System.out.println((display.getFirstName() + " " +
                display.getLastName() + " " + deletePeople.indexOf(display)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you should use Hashes/map as problem is indexOf it returns first occurrence, and you are having 2 same persons

Comment: Your code is not complete. What is `deletePeople`? Where is it declared?

Comment: @Jesper – Terriable sorry, it’s a list declared at the top.

Comment: @a question – Key value pair, I could still find my two objects and print the key associated with the object correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`indexOf` returns the index of the first occurence which is the same (according to the equals method) in the List. That's why you see both 1 printed.

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in
>   this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More
>   formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null
>   : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

And you can see the implementation (for `ArrayList`, but that's the same idea for a `LinkedList` except that you iterate other the nodes):

```
229  public int indexOf(Object o) {
230      if (o == null) {
231          for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
232              if (elementData[i]==null)
233                  return i;
234      } else {
235          for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
236              if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
237                  return i;
238      }
239      return -1;
240  }
```

If you want to print the index associated, you can use a counter that you increment at each iteration.

```
int index = 0;
for (Person display : deletePeople) {
    if(display.equals(checkPerson)){
        System.out.println((display.getFirstName() + " " + display.getLastName() + " " + index));
    }
    index++;
}
```

It would also be possible with a standard for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < deletePeople.size(); i++){
    Person display = deletePeople.get(i);
    if(display.equals(checkPerson)){
        System.out.println((display.getFirstName() + " " + display.getLastName() + " " + i));
    }
}
```

However be careful with the latter implementation because if the underlying representation of the list is a `LinkedList` the complexity of the above loop would be `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n)`.

Comment: @ ZouZou – What can I do to fix it?

Comment: @Nexusfactor why do you need a list? do you really need duplicates? If so, you have to loop through the list; if not, use a set.

Comment: @Giovanni Botta – This isn’t for anything in particular. It was just something I wanted to understand for myself. I have a List and I did loop though it, but it didn’t work.

Comment: @ ZouZou – Thank you VERY MUCH. Just for my own understanding. I wasn’t doing anything wrong, it was just the way indexof and equals function in Java, that’s why I was getting the incorrect result?

Comment: @Nexusfactor Yes, basically indexOf will start from the beginning of the List. When it encounter an object in the list that is equals to the one you pass in parameter, it returns the index of it, no matter if there is another object that is equals and after in the list.

Comment: @ ZouZou – This is a little late, but how did you get the code for the indexOf? Can you view the code inside the IDE or is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @Nexusfactor Yes you can view it in your IDE normally. Otherwise you have all the sources in a zip folder where you installed Java (C://Programmes/Java/jdk1.8.0/src.zip for me). Online you can check this at http://grepcode.com. Here's for `ArrayList`: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java

Answer (score 0):

By calling `indexOf()` you print the *first* index that matches, rather than the current index.  If you're interested in tracking your position in the list, the best thing is to do that manually, so instead of a for-each loop:

```
for(Object o : ls) {
  // the syntax is nice, but we don't have an easy way to
  // tell how far into the list we are
  System.out.println(o);
}
```

Instead, use a simple for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ls.size(); i++) {
  Object o = ls.get(i);
  // Now we have access to the object *and* its index
  System.out.println(i+": "+o);
}
```

---

Additionally, there's quite a few simple cleanups you could make in your code, if you'll forgive me, here's some suggestions:

1. [Avoid allowing `null` in your objects](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) - rarely is `null` actually meaningful, and allowing it forces all calling code to do null checks everywhere.

   ```
   public Person(String firstName,String lastName) {
     if(firstName == null || lastName == null) {
       throw new NullPointerException("First/Last name cannot be null");
     }
     this.firstName = firstName;
     this.lastName = lastName;
   }
   ```
2. Use `String.format()` correctly, or just avoid it.  Your current `toString()` method calls `String.format(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName)`, which doesn't actually do anything; you might as well just return the concatenated string without `String.format()`.  Alternatively, you can properly use the format functionality like so:

   ```
   String.format("%s %s", firstName, lastName);
   ```
3. Take advantage of Java 7's [`Objects`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) class for your `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods:

   ```
   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       return Objects.hash(firstName, lastName);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (this == obj)
           return true;
       if (obj == null)
           return false;
       if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
           return false;
       Person other = (Person) obj;
       return Objects.equals(firstName, other.firstName) &&
              Objects.equals(lastName, other.lastName);
   }
   ```

Comment: – Thanks for the explanation and corrections, much appreciated. This code was just for my own understanding and it’s not for any project in particular. I’m already aware how not to create object with null values, but don’t delete or remove your answer. It will be helpful to me in the future, if needed.